# pip install face_recognition выдаёт ошибку

Tags: pip, install

Здравствуйте при скачивании библиотеки[image: код при ввода pip install face_recognition] face_recognition Выдаёт вот такую ошибку

подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй установить dlib

```
pip install dlib
```

[Dlib installation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может возникать, если ты после установки новейшей версии пытался установить более старую.
Решение показано в видео - [тык](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__cfmdlVv5g).